# Bloquear o aumento de janela

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso bloquear o aumento da janela `QDialog` e `QWidget`?

Por exemplo, na janela de login do Skype você não consegue aumentar a janela.

Answer (score 3):

No construtor você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
setFixedSize(size());
```

Ou ainda assim para usar o tamanho recomendável em vez do padrão:

```
setFixedSize(sizeHint());
```

Assim o tamanho máximo e mínimo da janela serão setados para o mesmo valor, ela não será redimensionável.

Uma melhor forma de fazer isso (que vai redimensionar a janela se o conteúdo mudar, mas vai fazer a janela ser sempre a ideal para o seu conteúdo) é usando `QLayout::SetFixedSize`. Ver a [resposta do C. E. Gesser](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9648/429).

Adicionalmente, você pode setar a flag `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` que no Windows cria uma janela com borda fina, indicando visualmente ao usuário que não é redimensionável.

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

Comment: Blz. adicionei nos QDialog. Outra dúvida no MainWindows. Gostaria que redirecionasse os componeste do layout quando aumenta a janela. você sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: @user628298 Na entendi a questão, usando layouts os componentes naturalmente se redimensionam ao tamanho do contêiner. Mas parece não relacionado, provavelmente cabe [abrir uma nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ok, vou criar uma nova pergunta. obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método `setFixedSize(const QSize &)` da classe `QWidget` para definir um tamanho fixo para uma janela. Na prática ele define o tamanho máximo e o mínimo da janela para o valor que for passado por parâmetro.

Se você quiser que o tamanho seja fixo mas baseado nos componentes da janela, use o `setSizeConstraint(SizeConstraint)` da classe `QLayout`, com o parâmetro `SetFixedSize`:

```
layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

Comment: Blz. adicionei nos QDialog. Outra dúvida no MainWindows(QWidget). Gostaria que redirecionasse os componentes do layout quando aumenta a janela. você sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: @user628298 Isto seria o normal de acontecer quando se usa layouts. Talvez você possa editar a questão adicionando essa dúvida, e indicando qual layout você está usando e talvez uma captura de tela de como está ficando errado. Ou talvez seja melhor criar outra pergunta até para isso.

Comment: Ok, vou criar uma nova pergunta. obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método [`setFixedSize`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize) para fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
setFixedSize(this->geometry().width(),this->geometry().height());
```